# Puzzled with a separable ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In the book "Ordinary Differential Equations and Applications: Mathematical Methods for Applied Mathematicians, Physicists, Engineers and Bioscientists" ( W. S. Weiglhofer and K. A. Lindsay) the authors study the IVP: $y'=3xy^{1/3}$, $y(0)=0$.

To solve the problem they used the separation of variables method.
\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx}& = 3xy^{1/3}\Rightarrow \int y^{-1/3} dy = \int 3x dx \\
\frac{3}{2}y^{2/3}&=\frac{3}{2}x^2+\frac{3}{2}C\Rightarrow y^{2/3} = x^2+C\Rightarrow y = \pm \left(x^2+C\right)^{3/2}
\end{align*}
To cite the authors, *[F]rom the initial condition, $C = 0$ and thus both $y = x^3$ and $y = -x^3$
are particular solutions. However, $y = 0$ is also a solution! This solution
is not accessible to the separation of variables procedure which explicitly
assumes that it is permissible to divide by $y^{1/3}$ , that is, $y$ is at worst zero
at discrete points and not over an interval of finite length. Thus this initial
value problem has a non-unique solution. The solution $y=0$ is a singular solution.*

I cannot understand why one can separate the variables since this demands that $y\neq 0$. Any insight will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: If $y = 0$, what would $\int\, y^{-1/3}\, dy$ correspond to?

Comment: @Aruralreader Sorry, I don't get it. If $y=0$ how we can divide by $y$ the original equation $\frac{dy}{dx}= 3xy^{1/3}$?

Comment: You can temporarily assume $y\not=0$ for the purposes of the separation-of-variables process. You get whatever solutions you get - in this case, $\pm x^3.$ You do not get any solutions through separation-of-variables that contradicts $y\not=0,$ namely, $y=0.$ There's no contradiction, here. There would be a contradiction if separation of variables led to $y=0$ contrary to its own assumption! You get $y=0$ as a solution simply by inspection, but not by separation of variables.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thanks a lot! I understand what you say. But still, there is not any contradiction with the condition $y(0) = 0$? How can we justify formally that one can temporarily assume y≠0, solve the differential equation by the Separation of Variables method and then apply the condition to have the particular solutions?

Comment: You bring up a good point. But ODEs is an interesting subject in that there are lots of "hacked" solution methods that skirt the edges of logic, so to speak. That's why mathematicians have been so keen on proving existence and uniqueness of solutions whenever they can, because then any method, no matter how "rough", if it provides a solution that satisfies the ODE (usually a straight-forward process), is acceptable. The book from which you're working is not written for mathematicians, but for physicists and engineers, etc., who often don't care so much about rigor.

Comment: It's akin to some methods for finding real roots of polynomials that unavoidably make detours through complex numbers, only to land on real numbers in the end. The solutions are demonstrably correct, in that they satisfy the equation.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thanks a lot! But what is the interval of validity of the solution(s) in this case? If the IVP was $y'=3xy^{1/3}$ and $y(1)=1$ the solution is unique $y(x) = x^{1/3}$ and the interval of validity is $0<x<\infty$. If the IVP was $y'=3xy^{1/3}$ and $y(1)=-1$ the solution is unique $y(x) = -x^{1/3}$ and the interval of validity is $-\infty<x<0$. But for the IVP $y'=3xy^{1/3}$ and $y(0)=0$ can we speak about interval of validity?  [https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/IoV.aspx]